# How to run sikuli script inside robot framework?

Tags: python, jython, robotframework, sikuli

I have automated the following scenario using sikuli:

```
STEP 1: Launch a application by clicking on icon in windows desktop
STEP 2: Input Username
STEP 3: Input Password
STEP 4: Click Launch button.
```

Its working as expected.

Now I am want to run this using Robot Framework, So that I can integrate all other work with this.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to execute your test on windows here's what you need to do:

1. Create a batch script with the following content. Change the script accordingly. 
   pythonpath should have point to your sikuli project, which must have the keyword definitions.

robottest.bat

```
@echo off

set sikuli_jar=C:\Program Files\Sikuli X\sikuli-script.jar
set robotframework_jar=C:\YourProject\robotframework-2.8.1.jar

java -cp "robotframework-2.8.1.jar;%sikuli_jar%" ^
-Dpython.path="%robotframework_jar%\Lib";"%sikuli_jar%\Lib" ^
org.robotframework.RobotFramework ^
--pythonpath=your-project.sikuli ^
--outputdir=TestResults ^
--noncritical non-critical ^
--loglevel=TRACE ^
%*
```

2. Execute the following command to run your tests.

   robottest Tests/.
3. Your project can have following directory structure.

YourProject -> a. **Tests** (This directory will contain your tests)

b. **TestResults** (This directory will contain your test results)

c. **your-project.sikuli** (This will contain libraries with keyword definitions)

Answer (score 2):

1. If you use sikuli IDE, and saved your test case as sikuli script. You could execute the sikuli scripts in RobotFramework test cases.
2. Another option is using existed Sikuli robot framework library. There are some projects in GitHub. And you could search "sikuli robot", and could find many projects.

I am trying to implement a library to integrate Sikuli to Robot Framework recently. Here is link: https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/

You could have a try, if you are interested with this.