# Robot framework support for embedded system HMI Testing

Tags: testing, embedded, robotframework

Is there any support for testing an embedded system GUI using Robot framework. 
I have gone through few post on this but doesn't find any concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this old stack overflow post can help you.

[How to run sikuli script inside robot framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105312/how-to-run-sikuli-script-inside-robot-framework)

Sikuli can be used along with Robot Framework for GUI testing.

Here the link to the git project for robotframework-SikuliLibrary:
https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/

Hopefully, this is what you are looking for.